# Handsontable in Vue.js standalone

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use `Vue.js` as a standalone app (without `npm` packages), and was trying to get `handsontable` to render inside the app, without success.

This is my current configuration inside the `html` file:

```
<body>

    <div class="container" id="app">
            <div>
                <hot-table :settings="settings" licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@handsontable/vue/dist/vue-handsontable.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        data: [
          ['', 'Tesla', 'Mercedes', 'Toyota', 'Volvo'],
          ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
          ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
          ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
        ],
        components: {
          HotTable
        }

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

But I am getting an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: HotTable is not defined

What is the correct way to include an external component inside a standalone `Vue.js` app? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information is all in their documentation, albeit not beginner friendly.

https://github.com/handsontable/vue-handsontable-official

The code example is for compiled Vue (using `import`), but for CDN use, it states:

> The component will be available as `Handsontable.vue.HotTable`

so you can't reference the component with `HotTable`, but have to use the namespaced version: `components: {HotTable: Handsontable.vue.HotTable}`

Also, your `data` is not declared properly, and you aren't passing any data to the `hot-table` component.

### TL;DR;

#### Here's what it should look like:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    HotTable: Handsontable.vue.HotTable
  },
  data: function() {
    return{
      tableData: [
        ['', 'Tesla', 'Mercedes', 'Toyota', 'Volvo'],
        ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
      ]
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@handsontable/vue/dist/vue-handsontable.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div>
    <hot-table :data="tableData" licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A free open source alternative:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-default-template-p4hwn

```
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.js"></script>
<script src="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/jexcel.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bossanova.uk/jsuites/v2/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="spreadsheet"></div>

<input type="button" value="Add new row" onclick="vm.insertRow()" />

<script>
var options = {
    data:[[]],
    minDimensions:[10,10],
}

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#spreadsheet',
    mounted: function() {
        let spreadsheet = jexcel(this.$el, options);
        Object.assign(this, spreadsheet);
    }
}); 
</script></html>
```